# ToDo APP Border color change depending on priority

Tags: javascript, html, css

I been wondering if there is any way to add a color depending on the selected priority into a ToDo List Card/Activity created.

I been trying to make this change into a ToDo APP that was created in freeCodeCamp JS, the name of it is “Learn Local Storage by building a ToDo APP”.

Anything helps.

(Edit)
I apologize for not being specific, it is my first post after all.

I have tried getting the task’s id but I failed due to my lack of knowledge, I also attempted to make a addEventListener to change it’s class and failed, and finally I tried putting the buttons inside the JS and use a function to change it’s border color and failed.

This is all the JS code:

```
const taskForm = document.getElementById("task-form");
const confirmCloseDialog = document.getElementById("confirm-close-dialog");
const openTaskFormBtn = document.getElementById("open-task-form-btn");
const closeTaskFormBtn = document.getElementById("close-task-form-btn");
const addOrUpdateTaskBtn = document.getElementById("add-or-update-task-btn");
const cancelBtn = document.getElementById("cancel-btn");
const discardBtn = document.getElementById("discard-btn");
const tasksContainer = document.getElementById("tasks-container");
const titleInput = document.getElementById("title-input");
const dateInput = document.getElementById("date-input");
const descriptionInput = document.getElementById("description-input");

const taskData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || [];
let currentTask = {};

const addOrUpdateTask = () => {
  addOrUpdateTaskBtn.innerText = "Add Task";
  const dataArrIndex = taskData.findIndex((item) => item.id === currentTask.id);
  const taskObj = {
    id: `${titleInput.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}-${Date.now()}`,
    title: titleInput.value,
    date: dateInput.value,
    description: descriptionInput.value,
  };

  if (dataArrIndex === -1) {
    taskData.unshift(taskObj);
  } else {
    taskData[dataArrIndex] = taskObj;
  }

  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(taskData));
  updateTaskContainer();
  reset();
};

const updateTaskContainer = () => {
  tasksContainer.innerHTML = "";

  taskData.forEach(({ id, title, date, description }) => {
    let priorityClass = '';
    let priorityBorder = '';
    switch (id % 3) {
      case 0:
        priorityClass = 'high';
        priorityBorder = 'red';
        break;
      case 1:
        priorityClass = 'medium';
        priorityBorder = 'orange';
        break;
      case 2:
        priorityClass = 'low';
        priorityBorder = 'green';
        break;
    }

    tasksContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="task ${priorityClass}" id="${id}" style="border: 4px solid ${priorityBorder};">
          <p><strong>Title:</strong> ${title}</p>
          <p><strong>Date:</strong> ${date}</p>
          <p><strong>Description:</strong> ${description}</p>
          <button onclick="editTask(this)" type="button" class="btn">Edit</button>
          <button onclick="deleteTask(this)" type="button" class="btn">Delete</button> 
          <h2 class="priori">Priority assignment</h2>
          <button class="small-btn priori">high</button>
          <button class="small-btn priori">medium</button>
          <button class="small-btn priori">low</button>
        </div>
      `;
  });
};

const deleteTask = (buttonEl) => {
  const dataArrIndex = taskData.findIndex((item) => item.id === buttonEl.parentElement.id);

  buttonEl.parentElement.remove();
  taskData.splice(dataArrIndex, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(taskData));
};

const editTask = (buttonEl) => {
  const dataArrIndex = taskData.findIndex((item) => item.id === buttonEl.parentElement.id);

  currentTask = taskData[dataArrIndex];

  titleInput.value = currentTask.title;
  dateInput.value = currentTask.date;
  descriptionInput.value = currentTask.description;

  addOrUpdateTaskBtn.innerText = "Update Task";

  taskForm.classList.toggle("hidden");
};

const reset = () => {
  titleInput.value = "";
  dateInput.value = "";
  descriptionInput.value = "";
  taskForm.classList.toggle("hidden");
  currentTask = {};
};

if (taskData.length) {
  updateTaskContainer();
}

openTaskFormBtn.addEventListener("click", () => taskForm.classList.toggle("hidden"));

closeTaskFormBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const formInputsContainValues = titleInput.value || dateInput.value || descriptionInput.value;
  const formInputValuesUpdated =
    titleInput.value !== currentTask.title || dateInput.value !== currentTask.date || descriptionInput.value !== currentTask.description;

  if (formInputsContainValues && formInputValuesUpdated) {
    confirmCloseDialog.showModal();
  } else {
    reset();
  }
});

cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => confirmCloseDialog.close());

discardBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  confirmCloseDialog.close();
  reset();
});

taskForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  addOrUpdateTask();
});
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78157463/edit) the question to show the code that you tried? See [ask] for information about how to include a code snippet in your question.

Comment: *if there is any way to add a color depending on the selected priority* - there are many different ways using CSS

Comment: "*tried doing several things*" - Please add the (relevant) code of your attempt(s) inside the question - [ask]